# Issues with various alignments in table and a warning of misplaced \omit

Tags: tables, alignment

I am facing multiple issues in a table that I am trying to typeset. Following is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inner=1.5in,outer=1in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.25in,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,booktabs,multirow,multicol,tabularx,siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\sisetup{
    exponent-product={\times},
    retain-explicit-plus,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre    = false,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=3,
    table-space-text-pre    = (
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\sisetup{round-precision=2}
\centering
\caption{Table Caption}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llSSS}
\toprule
\multirow{3}[0]{*}{\textbf{Group}} 
&   \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\textbf{Attribute}} 
& {\multirow{3}[0]{*}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{c}
        \textbf{A long one:}\\ 
        \textbf{three line}\\ 
        \textbf{heading}
        \end{tabular}}}} 
&   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}{c}
        \textbf{Another one: two}\\ 
        \textbf{line heading}
        \end{tabular}} \\ 
  \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
    &   &   & {$\bm\mu$} & {$\bm\sigma$} \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Category One}
    & Part 1    & 9.40  & 1.25  & 99.23 \\
    & Part 2    & 30.93 & 3.92  & 22.43 \\
    & Part 3    & 11.33 & 55.22 & 1.11  \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Category Two}
    & Part 1    & 22.33 & 33.44 & 44.44 \\
    & Part 2    & 22.77 & 55.66 & 33.33 \\
    & Part 3    & 11.33 & 66.66 & 88.66 \\
    & Part 4    & 23.34  & 33.44  & 15.22 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{5}[0]{*}{
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
Two line\\ 
Category Name\\
\end{tabular}} 
& Part 1    & 22.22 & 33.44 & 44.55 \\
& Part 2    & 88.77 & 77.66 & 66.55 \\
& Part 3    & 6.66  & 22.11 & 55.55 \\
& Part 4    & 33.33  & 39.44  & 13.33 \\
& Part 5    & 2.22 & 1.11 & 6.66 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Category Last}     
& Part 1    & 44.55 & 66.33 & 44.55 \\
& Part 2    & 11.22 & 44.44 & 33.66 \\
& Part 3    & 1.22  & 11.11  & 5.65  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Please note that I am using `siunitx` in the MWE.

1. The values in the first two columns are left aligned.
2. The values in the remaining three columns are aligned at the decimal point (hence, the column type is 'S')
3. I am fine even if the values are right aligned as long as the column headings are well aligned w.r.t the values below them.

Here is a screenshot of the generated table. The issues indicated in the screenshot:
[image]

Further, I am also getting a warning of "Misplaced \omit".

Can anyone provide a solution to these issues?

Comment: What's not well aligned in the first row is not clear to me. Could you be more  explicit?

Comment: @Bernard The heading "Another one: two line heading" along with the cmidrule below appear shifted to the right as compared to the two columns (\mu and \sigma). It looks off balance.

Comment: That is because the heading is too large for the widths of the last two columns. It's possible to fix that. B.t.w., you didn't mention you load  `siunitx`, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @Bernard Yeah, you are right. I did not explicitly mention about `siunitx`. Sorry to cause trouble. I will edit the question. Please suggest how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inner=1.5in,outer=1in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.25in,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\sisetup{
    exponent-product={\times},
    retain-explicit-plus,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre    = false,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=3,
    table-space-text-pre    = (
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\sisetup{round-precision=2}
\centering
\caption{Table Caption}

\begin{NiceTabular}{llSSS}[columns-width=15mm]
\toprule
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
\Block{2-1}{Group} 
& \Block{2-1}{Attribute} 
& \Block{2-1}{A long one:\\ three line\\ heading} 
& \Block{1-2}{Another one: two\\ line heading} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
\RowStyle{\mathversion{bold}}
    &   &   & {$\mu$} & {$\sigma$} \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{Category One}
    & Part 1    & 9.40  & 1.25  & 99.23 \\
    & Part 2    & 30.93 & 3.92  & 22.43 \\
    & Part 3    & 11.33 & 55.22 & 1.11  \\ 
\midrule
\Block{4-1}{Category Two}
    & Part 1    & 22.33 & 33.44 & 44.44 \\
    & Part 2    & 22.77 & 55.66 & 33.33 \\
    & Part 3    & 11.33 & 66.66 & 88.66 \\
    & Part 4    & 23.34  & 33.44  & 15.22 \\ 
\midrule
\Block{5-1}{Two line\\ Category Name}
& Part 1    & 22.22 & 33.44 & 44.55 \\
& Part 2    & 88.77 & 77.66 & 66.55 \\
& Part 3    & 6.66  & 22.11 & 55.55 \\
& Part 4    & 33.33  & 39.44  & 13.33 \\
& Part 5    & 2.22 & 1.11 & 6.66 \\ 
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{Category Last}     
& Part 1    & 44.55 & 66.33 & 44.55 \\
& Part 2    & 11.22 & 44.44 & 33.66 \\
& Part 3    & 1.22  & 11.11  & 5.65  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

I propose this solution, which relies on the `makecell` package. I added some  code simplifications and improvements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inner=1.5in,outer=1in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.25in,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,booktabs,multirow,multicol,tabularx,siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell, caption}
\renewcommand{\theadfont} {\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theadset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\sisetup{
    exponent-product={\times},
    retain-explicit-plus,
    input-open-uncertainty = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre = false,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=3,
    table-space-text-pre = (
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\sisetup{round-precision=2, table-column-width=16mm}
\centering
\caption{Table Caption}
\begin{tabular}{llSSS}
\toprule
\multirow{3}[0]{*}{\textbf{Group}}
& \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\textbf{Attribute}}
& {\multirowcell{3}[1.35ex]{\thead{A long one:\\ three line \\ heading}}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{one: two\\ line heading} }\\[-0.5ex]
  \cmidrule(l{1em}r{1em}){4-5}
    & & & $\bm\mu$ & $\bm\sigma$ \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Category One}
    & Part 1 & 9.40 & 1.25 & 99.23 \\
    & Part 2 & 30.93 & 3.92 & 22.43 \\
    & Part 3 & 11.33 & 55.22 & 1.11 \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Category Two}
    & Part 1 & 22.33 & 33.44 & 44.44 \\
    & Part 2 & 22.77 & 55.66 & 33.33 \\
    & Part 3 & 11.33 & 66.66 & 88.66 \\
    & Part 4 & 23.34 & 33.44 & 15.22 \\
\midrule
\multirowcell{5}[0pt][l]{Two line\\ Category Name}
& Part 1 & 22.22 & 33.44 & 44.55 \\
& Part 2 & 88.77 & 77.66 & 66.55 \\
& Part 3 & 6.66 & 22.11 & 55.55 \\
& Part 4 & 33.33 & 39.44 & 13.33 \\
& Part 5 & 2.22 & 1.11 & 6.66 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Category Last}
& Part 1 & 44.55 & 66.33 & 44.55 \\
& Part 2 & 11.22 & 44.44 & 33.66 \\
& Part 3 & 1.22 & 11.11 & 5.65 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd not use `\multirow`: it adds nothing to clarity, except perhaps for the “Two line Category Name”, but I believe that in your real table the readers will understand that the two lines refer to the same category.

It wouldn't be so difficult to reinsert `\multirow` if you so desire, but in that case `\dosplitcell` must have `\begin{tabular}[c]` instead of `\begin{tabular}[t]`.

The problem with the header spanning the last two columns is that it is wider than the combined widths of the columns, so the excess goes in the last one. Add some space between the columns (the exact amount must be visually determined).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inner=1.5in,outer=1in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.25in,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm,booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{
    exponent-product={\times},
    retain-explicit-plus,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre    = false,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=3,
%    table-space-text-pre    = (
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitcell}{sO{c}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\smash{\dosplitcell{#2}{#3}}}{\dosplitcell{#2}{#3}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dosplitcell}{mm}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering

\sisetup{round-precision=2}

\caption{Table Caption}
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{\hspace{3em}}     % <---- adjust to suit
  S[table-format=2.2]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Group} & \textbf{Attribute} &
{\bfseries\splitcell*{A long one: \\ three line \\ heading}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\splitcell{Another one: \\ two line heading}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
    &   &   & {$\bm\mu$} & {$\bm\sigma$} \\
\midrule
Category One
  & Part 1    &  9.40 &  1.25 & 99.23 \\
  & Part 2    & 30.93 &  3.92 & 22.43 \\
  & Part 3    & 11.33 & 55.22 &  1.11 \\ 
\midrule
Category Two
  & Part 1    & 22.33 & 33.44 & 44.44 \\
  & Part 2    & 22.77 & 55.66 & 33.33 \\
  & Part 3    & 11.33 & 66.66 & 88.66 \\
  & Part 4    & 23.34 & 33.44 & 15.22 \\ 
\midrule
\splitcell*[l]{Two line \\ Category Name} 
  & Part 1    & 22.22 & 33.44 & 44.55 \\
  & Part 2    & 88.77 & 77.66 & 66.55 \\
  & Part 3    &  6.66 & 22.11 & 55.55 \\
  & Part 4    & 33.33 & 39.44 & 13.33 \\
  & Part 5    &  2.22 &  1.11 &  6.66 \\ 
\midrule
Category Last
  & Part 1    & 44.55 & 66.33 & 44.55 \\
  & Part 2    & 11.22 & 44.44 & 33.66 \\
  & Part 3    &  1.22 & 11.11 &  5.65 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And ***never*** rescale tables. If you want the table to fill the text width, use `tabular*`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inner=1.5in,outer=1in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.25in,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm,booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{
    exponent-product={\times},
    retain-explicit-plus,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre    = false,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=3,
%    table-space-text-pre    = (
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitcell}{sO{c}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\smash{\dosplitcell{#2}{#3}}}{\dosplitcell{#2}{#3}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dosplitcell}{mm}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering

\sisetup{round-precision=2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\caption{Table Caption}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{\hspace{3em}}     % <---- adjust to suit
  S[table-format=2.2]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Group} & \textbf{Attribute} &
{\bfseries\splitcell*{A long one: \\ three line \\ heading}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\splitcell{Another one: \\ two line heading}} \\
\cmidrule{4-5} 
    &   &   & {$\bm\mu$} & {$\bm\sigma$} \\
\midrule
Category One
  & Part 1    &  9.40 &  1.25 & 99.23 \\
  & Part 2    & 30.93 &  3.92 & 22.43 \\
  & Part 3    & 11.33 & 55.22 &  1.11 \\ 
\midrule
Category Two
  & Part 1    & 22.33 & 33.44 & 44.44 \\
  & Part 2    & 22.77 & 55.66 & 33.33 \\
  & Part 3    & 11.33 & 66.66 & 88.66 \\
  & Part 4    & 23.34 & 33.44 & 15.22 \\ 
\midrule
\splitcell*[l]{Two line \\ Category Name} 
  & Part 1    & 22.22 & 33.44 & 44.55 \\
  & Part 2    & 88.77 & 77.66 & 66.55 \\
  & Part 3    &  6.66 & 22.11 & 55.55 \\
  & Part 4    & 33.33 & 39.44 & 13.33 \\
  & Part 5    &  2.22 &  1.11 &  6.66 \\ 
\midrule
Category Last
  & Part 1    & 44.55 & 66.33 & 44.55 \\
  & Part 2    & 11.22 & 44.44 & 33.66 \\
  & Part 3    &  1.22 & 11.11 &  5.65 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]